# Text to speech in WinCE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce, text-to-speech

How to implement text to speech in WinCE 6.0?.
Can I use the Microsoft Speech API (SAPI) ?

I prefer C# but any example in another language is welcome.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SAPI is "supported" in Windows CE, but not actually functional.  No voices are included, so it's really not a viable solution.

You can try to get something like the open source [eSpeak](http://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/) working.  I've never tried it, and I don't know if they have ported it to CE, but it comes with full source so it might be worth investigating.

If you want something ready to use, with managed code support, [Chant](http://www.chant.net/Products/DeveloperWorkbench/requirements.aspx) is a commercial option that I know works.